# How to use temp table in SQL Server script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have to use some hardcode data in sql script, for this I am using temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    [Type] INT,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME,
    InterestRate DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO #Temp 
VALUES (1, '2015-07-01', '2017-05-01', 27),
       (1, '2017-05-02', '2017-06-30', 25.71)
```

On line 6, it is showing error as `Expecting Id`

Is there any simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `double` data type in `sql server` use `decimal`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    [Type] Int,
    StartDate DateTime,
    EndDate DateTime,
    InterestRate decimal
);

Insert Into #Temp Values 
(1,'2015-07-01','2017-05-01',27),
(1,'2017-05-02','2017-06-30',25.71)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQL` doesn't support `DOUBLE` ,you can use `float` or `decimal` instead of `DOUBLE`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    [Type] Int,
    StartDate DateTime,
    EndDate DateTime,
    InterestRate decimal
);

Insert Into #Temp Values 
(1,'2015-07-01','2017-05-01',27),
(1,'2017-05-02','2017-06-30',25.71)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `decimal`, but you need to give a `scale` and `precision`.  The default is `0` . . . which is not so useful for an interest rate.  See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a34346422996cae1129819f19ab87b7b).

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    [Type] INT,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME,
    InterestRate DECIMAL(10, 6)
);

INSERT INTO #Temp 
    VALUES (1, '2015-07-01', '2017-05-01', 27),
           (1, '2017-05-02', '2017-06-30', 25.71);
```

In addition, [SQL Server *does* have floating point types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  They are called `float` and `real`.  For financial purposes, I think `decimal`/`numeric` is a better choice.

Comment: @BlackCat . . . You may want to reconsider your accepted answer, because it does not store the data as you intend.